# Node.js -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a node.js file that is calling an async function and I keep getting a TypeError where property of "then" cannot be undefined at context.

**async.js**

```
if ( typeof window === 'undefined' ) {
  require('../../app/async');
  var expect = require('chai').expect;
}

describe('async behavior', function() {
  it('you should understand how to use promises to handle asynchronicity', function(done) {
    var flag = false;
    var finished = 0;
    var total = 2;

    function finish(_done) {
      if (++finished === total) { _done(); }
    }

    // This is where the error occurs
    asyncAnswers.async(true).then(function(result) {
      flag = result;
      expect(flag).to.eql(true);
      finish(done);
    });

    asyncAnswers.async('success').then(function(result) {
      flag = result;
      expect(flag).to.eql('success');
      finish(done);
    });

    expect(flag).to.eql(false);

    });
```

**app/async**

```
exports = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;

exports.asyncAnswers = {
  async: function(value) {

 },

 manipulateRemoteData: function(url) {

 }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `async` function in `app/async` needs to return a Promise object.  Right now, it isn't returning anything.

Comment: What kind of Promise object should I return in this case?

Comment: A Promise is basically just a wrapper around an asynchronous operation.  You can read more about them here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises.  Once you've read up on them, see if you can answer this question yourself.

Comment: I'm still having problems getting this code to execute properly since I cannot pass the proper <b>promise object</b> that will allow it to pass.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your async function in something like this using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object:

```
exports = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;

exports.asyncAnswers = {
  async: function(value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
      // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
      // use resolve to complete the promise successfully
      resolve(returnValueOrObject);
      // use reject to complete the promise with an error
      reject(errorGenerated);
    });
  },

  manipulateRemoteData: function(url) {

  }
};
```